# What can 侃大山 mean？

Tags: meaning

I'm a bit confused about the meaning of '侃大山’。 It means 'chat, chit-chat', 'gossip', 'brag'. Anything else? Is it still used or old-fashioned?

What exactly does '侃大山‘ mean? Where does this phrase come from?

Comment: bkrs：〈方〉漫无边际地聊天；闲聊。也作砍大山。
[piffle] [口]∶长时间没完没了地说一些琐碎、 不恰当或无效的话to chatter idly to gossip to boast or brag
syn. 砍大山 http://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BE%83%E5%A4%A7%E5%B1%B1 (引证解释also explains origin) jukuu has 6 sample sentences

Comment: It is an aimless, boastful babble about something grandiose with a lot of exaggeration. When Norman Maclean talked about his forest fire, that was an instance of 砍大山. Beijing Slang. Source unknown.

Answer (score 2):

It means people chatting. Similar to "聊天", "闲聊". It's not a regular used word. "侃" can be used to describe a person is a chat-box, like "他太能侃了".

Answer (score 1):

A more accurate translation would be "bullshitting".

Comment: Would it be possible to expand on this answer please?  E.g. provide reliable references, gives examples, describe its origin.

Comment: If you can read Chinese, here is a link in Chinese shows detailed explanations of 侃大山. https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BE%83%E5%A4%A7%E5%B1%B1

Comment: This is one got me laugh, I have to vote up.